# CMV (Configurable Map viewer) - Possible to use "Custom TiledMapServiceLayer" as a basemap?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, basemap, configurable-map-viewer, arcgis-online-basemaps

Is it possible to use a "[Custom TiledMapServiceLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_custom_tiled.html)" as a Basemap?
Is it possible to show a "Custom TiledMapServiceLayer" in [BasemapGallery](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_basemap.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely, your basemaps.js file would look something like the following:

```
define([
    'esri/dijit/Basemap',
    'esri/dijit/BasemapLayer',
    'esri/layers/osm'
], function ( Basemap, BasemapLayer, osm ) {
    return {
        map: true, // needs a reference to the map
        mode: 'custom', //must be either 'agol' or 'custom'
        title: 'Basemaps', // title for widget
        mapStartBasemap: 'topo', // must match one of the basemap keys below
        //basemaps to show in menu. define in basemaps object below and reference by name here
        // TODO Is this array necessary when the same keys are explicitly included/excluded below?
        basemapsToShow: ['topo', 'aerial'],

        // define all valid custom basemaps here. Object of Basemap objects. For custom basemaps, the key name and basemap id must match.
        basemaps: { // agol basemaps
            topo: {
                title: 'Map',
                basemap: new Basemap({
                    id: 'topo',
                    layers: [new BasemapLayer({
                        url: 'http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer',
                        opacity: 0.5
                    })]
                })
            },
```